# Find the optimal way to use combinations of summands to get the most sum with a limited number of summands

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, theory, combinations

I have a bit of a problem, I have a set of sums that add up to X, like so:

A: i + j + k = X

B: t + z = X

C: z + z = X

D: j + j + k + k = X

These sums can be more or less, I give 4 here but there could be N of them.

I have a limited number of summands so for example I have

12 of i, 35 of z, 12 of j, and 18 of k, 21 of t

what I need is an algorithm that will determine the best way to use those combinations so that I end up with the most complete sums of X

so in the example above using:

17 of combination C, 1 of combination B, and 12 of combination A, total 30 sums of X, 72 summands used

is worse then using:

21 of combination B, 7 of combination C, and 6 of combination D, total 34 sums of X, 80 summands used

Edit:

To further explain

using 21 of combination B will "spend" 21 t and 21 z leaving us with: 12 of i, 14 of z, 12 of j, 18 of k, 0 of t

using 7 of combination C will "spend" 14 of z (because it uses 2 summands of z to be achieved) leaving us with: 12 of i, 0 of z, 12 of j, 18 of k, 0 of t

using 6 of combination D will spend 12 of j and 12 of k (because it uses both of them twice) leaving us with: 12 of i, 0 of z, 0 of j, 6 of k, 0 of t

we can no longer make combinations that will add up to X thus the algorithm is concluded.

Comment: You'll have better luck here: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I have no idea what the question is. Or the premiss, for that matter.

Comment: This question isn't eve close to making any sense.

Comment: thanks @acheong87 I posted it there as well!

Comment: what exactly in the question does not make sense to you @RBarryYoung?

Comment: its theoretical @JiveDadson a way to compute the best way to use up i, j, k, z into X results with a limited number of i, j, k, z. So there is a "quantity" of i, j, k, z that needs to produce a quantity of X, how to best use i, j, k, z to get the most quantity of X.
Does that make things clearer things at all?

Comment: right @RBarryYoung I read what I wrote now and I see I didn't check the math, but I thought the point was coming across, ok edited it.

Comment: @ElijahVankov, is my interpretation correct? If so, feel free to use it to ask the question again http://pastebin.com/KyGa57F9

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a program to brute force this problem.

Which for your example data as the best possible combination gives:

> 1 of combination A, 19 of combination B, and 7 of combination C, 5 of
>   combination D, total 32 sums of X, 75 summands used

The code as it is although its not that neat and possibly not correct:

```
# Consider encoding the states
#{i,j,k}
#{i,z}
#{z,z}
#{j,j,k,k}
#as
#          i   z   j   k
limits =  (21, 35, 12, 18)
sets   = [(1,0,1,1), #
          (1,1,0,0), #
          (0,2,0,0), #
          (0,0,2,2), #
          ]

from heapq import heappush, heappop

def sub(A,B): return tuple(x - y for x,y in zip(A,B))

H = [(0,limits,[0]*len(sets))]
B = []
#X = 0
while H:
    #X += 1
    C, available, counts = heappop(H)
    #if X%1000 == 0: 
    #print C, available, counts
    if not any(all(not x > 0 for x in sub(available, s)) for s in sets):
        E = -C, sum(available), available, counts
        if E not in B:
            #print "found:", E
            if len(B) > 0:
                #print "best:", B[0]
                pass
            heappush(B, E)
    for i,s in enumerate(sets):
        diff = sub(available, s)
        if all(x > 0 for x in diff):
            counts_ = counts[:]
            counts_[i] += 1
            E = (C+1, diff, counts_)
            if E not in H:
                heappush(H, E)

a,b,c,d = heappop(B)

print "%u of combination A, %u of combination B, and %u of combination C, %u of combination D, total %u sums of X, %u summands used" % tuple(d+[-a, sum(limits)-sum(c)])
```

EDIT:

After entering the revisied problem into this program it produces in 9 seconds:

> 11 of combination A, 20 of combination B, and 7 of combination C, 0 of
>   combination D, total 38 sums of X, 87 summands used

The encoding of the revised problem:

```
#         i  z  j  k  t
limits = (12,35,12,18,21)
sets   = [(1,0,1,1,0), # {i,j,k}
          (0,1,0,0,1), # {t,z}
          (0,2,0,0,0), # {z,z}
          (0,0,2,2,0), # {j,j,k,k}
          ]
```

Comment: hmm but theres obviously a better solution then the result you give above no? I mean in my example the second one has 34 sums and 80 summands. Thanks tho!
Also I will probably need something more optimized then brute force for this one since in actual use this will need to deal with a lot of numbers :>

Comment: I began to doubt that your examples were possible with the limits on the parts. Note that it only took 8 seconds for that program to run.

Comment: right.. hmm I didn't check the math there, there was a silly mistake, take a peek now :>